# How to implement jsp browser action

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have two jsp pages one login.jsp page and one home.jsp page .After login it redirects to home.jsp page. when i hit browser  back  button it redirect back to login.jsp page .Instead of going to login.jsp page i need to refresh the home.jsp page . Can any one suggest any sample codes or methods  to solve this problem.

Comment: If the user uses the back button, it means that he wants to go back. If he wanted to stay on the current page, he wouldn't do anything, or he would hit Refresh. Maybe he wants to go back to log in as another user, who knows? Why don't you let him do what he wants with his browser? It's his browser, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to check in login.jsp if user is already loggined. if so redirect a home.jsp
Actually browsers don't have API to add eventListeners on their back button.
You can try different hooks using iframes, JS or others.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "cache-control" header as no-cache for login.jsp, in which case when the user presses the back button the page will be fetched again from the server where you can check if the user is already logged in, you can redirect him.